# Firebase Rules indexOn Order By

Tags: firebase, rules

I'm a little confused on how to "sort" child elements.

I've been using a Fusion Table (which I prefer), but my YouTube subscribers mostly use Firebase because they think Fusion is too hard... So I'm forced to come up with solutions for them, even though.. I don't like Firebase.

So here's the quandry.
I have a Firebase Hierarchy set up like this:
(I don't know how to format stack overflow -.-)

- FirebaseTutorial

  - users

    - **1234567890123**

      - username = "denise"
      - password = "peaches"
      - points = 500
    - **3210987654321**

      - username = "bob"
      - password = "boblaw"
      - points = 100

(This is not the full Firebase data)
Each **user** has a unique userID, based on SYSTEMTIME (so it's just a random 13 digit number) Each user shares the same tags, that display alphabetically in Firebase as:

1. password
2. points
3. timestamp
4. username

This morning, I grabbed all of the info for every user, and my data read sort of backwards: userID, username, timestamp, points, password

Then I added a 5th tag: high_score

Now my data reads in random order as: userID, timestamp, password, username, high_score, points

(The tags were created in this order: userID, username, password, points, timestamp, high_score)

What if I open my app tomorrow and my data reads again in another random order?

**Can I change the Rules in Firebase to read my data in a specific format?**
Something like indexOn: sort username, password, points...etc

Comment: Hey Nicholette. The rules don't influence the format in which data is exposed from the database. It only affects who can access, and what they can write. What Firebase Database are you using?

Comment: But in general: the order of properties in JSON is undefined. So while they may show up alphabetical, there is no guarantee of that. That's why Firebase has special structures in place (typically in the `Snapshot` classes) when ordering is considered important, e.g. when you retrieve things after calling `orderBy...()`.